# JAVA: Password digest generation algorithm leading to incorrect result

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a requirement to call SOAP 4.0 web service (based on Web service guide https://kupdf.net/download/soap-4-0-amadeus-wbs-implementation-guide_58c657a8dc0d605613339031_pdf ) that requires security header authentication. Unfortunately in my JAVA code, I am currently stuck in password parameter step - which is giving me Exception called

> 2019-02-25 19:06:36 ERROR ExceptionHandler:36 - Client Debug: 
>   11|Session| org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault:  11|Session|   at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1653)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.close(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)   at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:297)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:283)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:119)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.dlh.zambas.mw.client.ServiceProxy.callService(ServiceProxy.java:230)
>     at
>   com.dlh.zambas.mw.client.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:114)
>
> ERROR ExceptionHandler:39 - Client Debug: null

The password paramter requires Password digest generation algorithm which is of the format:

```
Base64(SHA1($NONCE + $TIMESTAMP + SHA1($CLEARPASSWORD)))
```

Where:
`Base64` is a binary-to-text encoding scheme;
`SHA1` is a cryptographic hash function;
`+` is the concatenation function;
`$NONCE` is an input parameter generated by the client's application;
`$TIMESTAMP` is an input parameter which represents current timestamp;
`$CLEARPASSWORD` is an input paramater - raw password.

Below is the snippet I am trying:

```
private String buildPasswordDigest(String nonce, String timestamp, String pass) {
        nonce=generateNonce();
        timestamp=generateTimestamp();
        pass="Test"
        try
        {
            MessageDigest msdDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            msdDigest.update(pass.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, pass.length());
            sha1_pass = byteToHex(msdDigest.digest());

            msdDigest.reset();

            String input_sha1= nonce+timestamp+sha1_pass;
            msdDigest.update(input_sha1.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, input_sha1.length());
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(msdDigest.digest());

        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return passwordDigest;
    }

private static String byteToHex(final byte[] hash){
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (byte b : hash)
    {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }
    String result = formatter.toString();
    formatter.close();
    return result;
}

private String generateNonce() {
    String dateTimeString = Long.toString(new Date().getTime());
    byte[] nonceByte = dateTimeString.getBytes();

    return Base64.encodeBase64String(nonceByte);
}

private String generateTimestamp() {
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
return dateFormatter.format(today);
}
```

Is it somehow not complying to the format?

Comment: give the full exception please and also the actual security specification for this webservice

Comment: log your outgoing soap message and see what it looks like.

Comment: Any luck with this?